# How to make 'copy as path' appear in Windows Explorer context menu without shift key?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

If I hold shift when opening the Windows Explorer context menu, an extra item appears, 'copy as path'. How can I make it so it always appears without having to hold shift?

I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: I'm surprised this didn't work; what version of Windows are you on?

Comment: this works fine. The **extended** entry controls if the entry is not shown by default and must be opened with Shift. I use this to hide entries that I don't use very often.

Comment: The trick in the other question only works for the Open Command Prompt here item.   Here's another potential, but not working, answer. http://superuser.com/questions/295484/unhide-windows-7-context-menu-extras-permanently

Comment: [Show "Copy as Path" Always in Right-Click Menu Without Shift Key](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/copy-as-path-always-show-right-click-windows-10/)

Answer (score 15):

This script works (**tested on Windows 10**) without invoking command prompt:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Allfilesystemobjects\shell\windows.copyaspath]
@="Copy &as path"
"Icon"="imageres.dll,-5302"
"InvokeCommandOnSelection"=dword:00000001
"VerbHandler"="{f3d06e7c-1e45-4a26-847e-f9fcdee59be0}"
"VerbName"="copyaspath"
```

It also assigns <kbd>a</kbd> as the hotkey on the context menu, so <kbd>RightClick</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> copies the file path.

Bonus: Script to remove the above setting:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Allfilesystemobjects\shell\windows.copyaspath]
```

[Script Credits](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/copy-as-path-always-show-right-click-windows-10/)

**Screenshot from Windows 10 Enterprise v1809 build 17763.437:**
[image: Copy as Path]

Comment: I can confirm that works on Win 10 Version 1709 64bit

Comment: This works still perfectly, no messy popups.

Comment: On Windows 7: "This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action..."

Comment: Worked fine for me, too. Also, the icon is a nice addition :-) Just a hint: the **position in the context menu is different** from the entry that appears when you use `Shift` + `Right click` - it appears close to the top. - I just noticed that you showed that on the screenshot @snag but I didn't look at that :-D

Answer (score 10):

AskVG [here](http://www.askvg.com/registry-tweak-to-add-copy-as-path-option-in-files-and-folders-context-menu-in-windows/) has a perfect solution. Though it says Windows 7, I've tried it on my Windows 10 PC and it works.

You can download the registry script straightaway from [here](http://media.askvg.com/downloads/2012/09/Add-Copy-as-Path-Option-in-Windows.zip). I've tested it and it contains no malicious code.

---

To prevent link rot, here are the contents of the REG file. Save the following as `copyaspath.reg` and then double-click to run.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;Created by Vishal Gupta for AskVG.com

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Copy as Path]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Copy as Path\command]
@="cmd.exe /c echo | set /p=\"\"%1\"\"|clip"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Copy as Path]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Copy as Path\command]
@="cmd.exe /c echo | set /p=\"\"%1\"\"|clip"
```

Kudos to @chunk_split for a workaround to remove the newline.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The command prompt just appeared and disappeared. Windows 7 32-bit.

Comment: @sunk818 Yeah, according to the comments, this doesn't work on Windows Xp or 7 but works on Windows 10. Don't know what the problem is but it works on my computer :)  (Windows 10 ver1511).

Comment: Check [my solution](https://superuser.com/a/1276520/167604). It doesn't do the command prompt _open-run-vanish_ trick.

Comment: This works very well, except it introduces an extra newline at the end (due to how `echo` works). You can use the following workaround to avoid that. Note the extra escaped quotes, escaped 2x, first time using backslashes for Windows Registry file format to get `""` needed for the `set /p` command resulting in finally a single `"` in your copied string, so the full line becomes:

`@="cmd.exe /c echo | set /p=\"\"%1\"\"|clip"`

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to comment on user Private's response but this looks correct. Here are the registry entries needed from the file he linked.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Copy as Path]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Copy as Path\command]
@="cmd.exe /c echo \"%1\"|clip"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Copy as Path]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Copy as Path\command]
@="cmd.exe /c echo \"%1\"|clip"
```

You can just save that as a .reg and run it.

Comment: You are unable to comment on my response? You could have just edited mine.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to add a comment unfortunately.

Comment: or edit my post?

Comment: I've edited Private's post. This post can safely be deleted.

Comment: @EngineerToast: I wouldn't count it as safe unless there's some record of Narzard's involvement on that question ;)

Comment: @SamB I agree. That's why I commented in an effort to ping Narzard to come my action. They should be able to edit now, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the REG file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Allfilesystemobjects\shell\CopyPath]
@="Copy Path"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Allfilesystemobjects\shell\CopyPath\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,63,00,6f,00,6d,00,73,00,70,00,65,00,63,00,25,00,20,00,2f,00,63,\
  00,20,00,3c,00,6e,00,75,00,6c,00,20,00,28,00,73,00,65,00,74,00,2f,00,70,00,\
  20,00,61,00,6e,00,79,00,76,00,61,00,72,00,69,00,61,00,62,00,6c,00,65,00,3d,\
  00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,29,00,7c,00,63,00,6c,00,69,00,70,00,2e,00,65,00,\
  78,00,65,00,00,00
```

([via Winhelponline](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/add-copy-as-path-right-click-menu-in-xp/)) I removed the "Extended" string value.

The hex code in the above REG file translates to this command-line:

```
%comspec% /c <nul (set/p anyvariable="%1")|clip.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, [SNag's](https://superuser.com/a/1276520/973057) answer is most elegant.

[Don't Root's](https://superuser.com/a/1061675/973057) answer works, but you may see a balck CMD window flash quickly sometimes,
and it does not support non-English characters. Here's an improved version from [1ocalhost](https://gist.github.com/1ocalhost/ab315ef3a61d658d451b3edf7e8f6d78).

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\Copy Path\command]
@="mshta vbscript:CreateObject(\"wscript.shell\").Run(\"cmd /c chcp 65001 && echo | set /p x=\"\"%1\"\" | clip\",0)(window.close)"
```

Because there's no [clip.exe](https://www.c3scripts.com/tutorials/msdos/clip.html) in Windows XP by default, [1ocalhost](https://gist.github.com/1ocalhost/de55450d8867c6be80d263d54c56e070) also provide another version for Windows XP:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\Copy Path\command]
@="mshta vbscript:Execute(\"set o=CreateObject(\"\"InternetExplorer.Application\"\")\"&vbcrlf&\"o.Navigate(\"\"about:blank\"\")\"&vbcrlf&\"o.document.parentwindow.clipboardData.setData \"\"text\"\", \"\"%1\"\"\"&vbcrlf&\"o.Quit\"&vbcrlf&\"window.close\")"
```