# How to edit windows 11 context menu "Copy as path" option?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, context-menu, windows-11, regedit

Windows 11 context menu has a default option, "Copy as path":
[Windows 11 context menu image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwbX0.png)

It is handy during programming, but "\"s are annoying during python programming. Is there any way to make a second option in the context menu with "/" as path joiner?

for example:

**This is what is copied to my clipboard:**
"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\NVIDIA Canvas.lnk"

**Desired:**
"C:/Users/Public/Desktop/NVIDIA Canvas.lnk"

Comment: Don't use normal strings for path. Use raw string literal and you'll never need to care about backslashes. It depends on language: `r'C:\Users\Public\Desktop\NVIDIA Canvas.lnk'` in python, `R"(C:\Users\Public\Desktop\NVIDIA Canvas.lnk)"` in C++, `@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\NVIDIA Canvas.lnk"` in C#... And there are other tools to give different kinds of path copy options in the extra context menu: [Unhide Windows 7 context menu extras permanently](https://superuser.com/a/1177703/241386)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unhide Windows 7 context menu extras permanently](https://superuser.com/questions/295484/unhide-windows-7-context-menu-extras-permanently)

Comment: You can use a custom script for copying the file paths in the required format. For example: [Copy as Path Without Quotes or in File URI Format](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/copy-as-path-without-quotes-file-uri-format/)

Comment: @w32sh Thank you, that was helpful. And phuclv, thanks for your response.